# Uncaught Error: Class "Application\NuevaClase" not found in

Tags: php, poo

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto sencillo que incorpora autoload con composer, pero por alguna razon autoload no funciona correctamente y me lanza este error:

```
Fri Apr  9 23:03:22 2021] [::1]:40550 [500]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "Application\NuevaClase" not found in /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/includes/app.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/index.php(12): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/includes/app.php on line 7
```

**Este es el arbol de mi proyecto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el código de los archivos que utilice:

**PruebaAutp.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application;

class NuevaClase{
    
}

?>
```

**app.php**

```
<?php
    require 'funciones.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    use Application\NuevaClase;

    $nuevo = new NuevaClase; //Al instaciar la clase se detona el error
    var_dump($nuevo);

?>
```

**funciones.php**

```
<?php

define('TEMPLATE_URL',__DIR__.'/templates');

function insertTemplate(string $nombre):void{
    include  TEMPLATE_URL."/${nombre}.php";
}

?>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "angel/prueba-proyecto",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Angel",
            "email": "correo@correo.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\":"clases/"
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        require 'includes/app.php';
        insertTemplate('header');
        
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**header.php**

```
<h1> Algun Texto </h1>
```

**--------- Edición ---------**

Renombrado el archivo: **/clases/PruebaAuto.php**
Renombrando la clase:

```
namespace App;
class PruebaAuto{}
```

**Error persiste:**

```
Sat Apr 10 11:01:13 2021] [::1]:40100 [500]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "App\PruebaAuto" not found in /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/includes/app.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/index.php(12): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/angel/Escritorio/PruebaProyecto/includes/app.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el nombre de tu archivo *PruebaAuto.php* no corresponde con el de la clase que contiene.

De la especificación *PSR-4*<sup>1</sup> extraigo y cito:

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

Que se puede traducir como:

> El nombre de la clase de terminación corresponde a un nombre de archivo que termina en .php. El nombre del archivo DEBE coincidir con el caso del nombre de la clase de terminación.

Entonces debe alcanzar con elegir alguno de estos caminos:

- Toma el nombre de la clase y asignalo como nombre del archivo

  ```
   <?php  //archivo NuevaClase.php

   class NuevaClase
   {

   }
  ```
- Toma el nombre del archivo y asignalo como el nombre de la clase

  ```
   <?php  //archivo PruebaAuto.php

   class PruebaAuto
   {

   }
  ```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Especificación para la auto carga de clases](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification)

Comment: Hola prove tu consejo pero aun sigue fallando, renombre mi archivo y mi clase y sigue gual

Comment: construi un nuevo proyecto y funciono sin problema tal vez fue un error del sistema o algo por el estilo... Por que duplique mi códgio que funciona en este código que subi y sigue presentando el mismo error .. Pero lo coloque en otro nuevo proyecto y ya funciono gracias por tu aporte